# Web App to iPhone calendar two-way sync

Tags: php, iphone, calendar

My Web App (PHP) needs to fetch my availability from my iPhone calendar and show which available slots I have in a given time frame. Conversely, those time slots can be booked by the Web App user which should then show up on my iPhone.

Can this be done? Is there an API for this? Or must one go through the extra step of syncing with an external service, and then again: can it be done?